# Branch SDK Params is empty when app is opened using any app such as WhatsApp or Messages

Tags: ios, branch.io

I am creating a `Universal Link` using `Branch` with the following code

```
       let buo = BranchUniversalObject.init(canonicalIdentifier: story.identifier)
        buo.title              = "Story".localized
        buo.contentDescription = story.story

        buo.contentMetadata.customMetadata.setValue(story.identifier, forKey: "identifier")
        buo.contentMetadata.customMetadata.setValue("StoryDetailViewController", forKey: "controller")
        let properties = BranchLinkProperties()
        properties.addControlParam("navigate_to", withValue: "StoryDetailViewController")
        properties.feature = "sharing"
        properties.channel = "facebook"
        properties.addControlParam("$deeplink_path", withValue: "StoryDetailViewController/\(story.identifier!)")

        buo.showShareSheet(with: properties, andShareText: "Story", from: controller) { (value, status) in

        }
```

If I open the URL using any app such as `WhatsApp` or `Messages` the params are the just default ones

```
{"+clicked_branch_link": 0,"+is_first_session": 0}
```

But if I open the same link in Safari browser, it opens the landing page with options "Get The App" and "Open the App". Clicking on "Open the App" fetches the params correctly.

[image: Landing Page]

```
{
    "+is_first_session": 0,
    "+clicked_branch_link": 1,
    "~marketing": 1,
    "~campaign": "MyCampaign",
    "$one_time_use": 0,
    "$canonical_identifier": "5d73deba06c4123c3422f77f",
    "story_id": "5d73deba06c4123c3422f77f",
    "~referring_link": "https: //momslunchbox.test-app.link/FNiMbQOoWZ",
    "~channel": "Facebook",
    "~id": 700923352042871377,
    "~feature": "sharing",
    "Controller": "StoryDetailViewController",
    "$marketing_title": "MyStory",
    "+click_timestamp": 1568351414,
    "~creation_source": 1,
    "+match_guaranteed": 1
}
```

Comment: One more interesting finding, when the link is 3D touched, it opens the preview for a second and then navigates to the app correctly and Branch is able to fetch the params correctly. But not with the normal/standard click on the link.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is related to how you are creating the links, this looks like a problem with the link setup on Branch dashboard. Can you make sure you have setup Universal links correctly? You will need to make sure you have the Apple app Prefix and Bundle identifier set correctly.

If the issue persists please reach out to Branch through support@branch.io

Comment: Checked multiple times and validated the links are correct. As I mentioned, when this link is opened using the button provided on landing page, it does fetch all the params those were set in the link.